# Convert lines from factor to numeric?

Tags: r

this example:

```
dat=structure(list(X = structure(c(1L, 2L,3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), X10 = structure(c(1L,2L,3L), .Label = c("3","0", "2"), class = "factor"), X11 = structure(c(1L, 2L,3L), .Label = c("0", "2", "0"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)) 

 dat=dat[,-1]

 fi=as.numeric(as.character(dat[1,] ))

 > fi
[1] 1 1
```

Which is not correct. I wonder what is wrong ?

Comment: if you are doing it for the first row, then do `as.numeric(as.character(unlist(dat[1,])))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as.numeric` is for vector, you need to use apply if you want to apply this to a data frame:

```
apply(dat, MARGIN=2,FUN=as.numeric)
```

result:

```
      X10 X11
[1,]   3   0
[2,]   0   2
[3,]   2   0
```

Comment: They are the column titles, it doesn't look like so because I copied it from R console.

Answer (score 1):

For multiple columns of different class, we can have a check whether it is `factor` or not to do the conversion

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))))
```

and if all the columns are `factor`, then use `mutate_all`

```
dat %>%
   mutate_all(funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))))
```

---

The `base R` way if all columns are `factor`, use `lapply` and assign it to the original object

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```